# How can i achieve text recognition functionality through camera in react-native IOS

Tags: react-native, image-recognition, firebase-mlkit, google-mlkit, text-recognition

Although i use **react-native-camera** for this but when i use **onTextRecognized** method of **react native camera** it **crashed the app when open camera in android**

**stack trace:**
**"react-native": "0.71.3",**
**"react-native-camera": "^4.2.1",**

Although i got some luck by using **react native image crop picker** to take picture and the crop it and then retrieve text from it by using.**react-native-ml-kit/text-recognition** which is working fine but i don't want that ,

what i want is open camera show detection on camera and without any click the  recognized text should be add in my flatlist and the procedure continue camera should not be close

Expected behaviour:
[Detect text from camera and show boxes on camera](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YPpJb.jpg)

[detected text in List when i close camera](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jghNL.jpg)